# Dominated Convergence Thm (DCT) for Double Sequences

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, convergence-divergence

By a version of the Dominated Convergence Theorem (Thm 25.12 in Billingsley 86)

$ E(X_n)\rightarrow E(X) $,  if $X_n \overset{p}{\rightarrow} X$ and $X_n$ is uniformly integrable sequence of random variables.

Does a similar result for double sequences of random variables $X_{mn}$ exist?

In particular consider the concept of a joint limit defined by the following equivalence

$\lim_{\{n,m\} \to \infty}a_{mn}=a \Leftrightarrow (\forall \epsilon>0 \;\exists N : (n,m>N \Rightarrow |a_{mn}-a|<\epsilon))$.

If $X_{mn}<Y$, i.e. it exists a RV $Y$ that dominates $X_{mn}$ pointwise,

does $\forall \delta>0: \lim_{\{n,m\} \to \infty} P(|X_{mn}-X|>\delta)=0$ 
imply $\lim_{\{n,m\} \to \infty}E(X_{mn})=E(X)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can actually prove the following:

> If $\{X_{m,n},m,n\geqslant 1\}$ is uniformly integrable and $\lim_{\min\{m,n\}\to \infty}X_{m,n}=X$ in probability, then $\lim_{\min\{m,n\}\to \infty}\mathbb E(X_{m,n})=\mathbb E(X)$.

Indeed, assume the conclusion does not hold: there is $\varepsilon>0$ and sequences of integers $(m_k,k\geqslant 1)$, $(n_k,k\geqslant 1)$ such that $\min\{m_k,n_k\}\uparrow\infty$ and $|\mathbb E(X_{m_k,n_k})-\mathbb E(X)|>\varepsilon$ for each $k$.

Now, define $Y_k:=X_{m_k,n_k}$. Then $\{Y_k,k\geqslant 1\}$ is uniformly integrable and $Y_k\to X$ in probability. We thus get a contradiction with the statement in the OP.

Comment: Davide Giraudo's answer does the Trick for me. Thanks, this result is exactly what I was looking for. If someone knows a reference for this result, please let us know.

Comment: Does a similar result hold for pointwise Cauchy sequences? i.e. if $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a sequence of bounded measurable functions with $|X_m-X_n|\xrightarrow{m,\:n\:\to\:\infty}0$, are we able to conclude $\int|X_m-X_n|\:{\rm d}\mu\xrightarrow{m,\:n\:\to\:\infty}0$ ($\mu$ being any measure)?