# Dominated convergence theorem for the product of two sequences

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Suppose $X_1, \dotsc, X_n$ is a sequence of IID random variables defined on a probability space $(\Omega, F, P)$, with finite mean and variance. Define $\bar X_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum X_i $, we know that $\bar X_n \overset{p}{\to} E[X]$.

Assume that there are two bounded continuous functions $f$ and $g$ such that $f \leq g$, and $f(\bar X_n ) \overset{p}{\to} 1$ and $g(\bar X_n ) \overset{p}{\to} 1$. Can I claim the following convergence by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/448931/dominated-convergence-thm-dct-for-double-sequences) version of Dominated Convergence Theorem?

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n E[f(\bar X_n) X_i] = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} E\left[f(\bar X_n)\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n  X_i\right] \leq E\left[\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} g(\bar X_n) \bar X_n\right] = E[X]
$$

Comment: I don't think the inequality step is justified.